# How to properly size nested tables in a .DOCX?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to create a .docx document, using Apache POI, which is expected to contain a table of Key-Value pairs. Some keys may have another set of Key-Value pair (instead of a single string value), which means I need to create a table inside another table.

Example table
[image]

I hoped that this would be easy to implement if I started from a document template, created in MS Word, so that it already has all the desired formatting. And, it kind of works, for the most part. The only problem is that in cases when there is a nested table in the generated document, MS Word will show a message about the file having some errors and whether he wants Word to recover it, when the user tries to open the file. After clicking 'Yes', the "recovered" file will appear correct.

As you can see in the above example image, I want it to have an "indent" for the next level (nested table). Which is achieved by having the template table formatted with 97% width and right alignment.

From what I could find, the differences in the document.xml from the "recovered" document to the one I created are only in the values for column width in the <w:tblGrid> element. However, It still unclear to me how those values are calculated.

I have tried adjusting the <w:tblGrid> in the nested table by setting the width to 97% of those in the parent table, and played a bit around that idea. But, still no lucky.

If I force it to be generated with the exact same values, then it will be opened by MS Word without any errors. So this confirms the grid sizes are the problem. But, of course, I can't rely on hard-coded values.

Comment: [Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please.

Answer (score 0):

I would not see the table in the picture in your question to be table in table. The table-in-table-construct is not really good practice. It should be avoided if possible.

I see a table having 4 columns where in rows 1, 2 and 5 columns 1 and 2 as well as 3 and 4 are merged. In rows 3 and 4 column 1 is hidden and columns 2 and 3 are merged.

Following code produces this using Apache POI (current version 5.2.3).

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordKeyValueTable {
    
 static void mergeCellHorizontally(XWPFTable table, int row, int fromCol, int toCol) {
  XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(row).getCell(fromCol);
  // Try getting the TcPr. Not simply setting an new one every time.
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTcPr tcPr = cell.getCTTc().getTcPr();
  if (tcPr == null) tcPr = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
  // The first merged cell has grid span property set
  if (tcPr.isSetGridSpan()) {
   tcPr.getGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(toCol-fromCol+1));
  } else {
   tcPr.addNewGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(toCol-fromCol+1));
  }
  // Cells which join (merge) the first one, must be removed
  for(int colIndex = toCol; colIndex > fromCol; colIndex--) {
   table.getRow(row).removeCell(colIndex); // use only this for apache poi versions greater than 4.1.1
  }
 }
 
 static void createGrid(XWPFTable table, int[] colWidths) {
  //create CTTblGrid for this table with widths of the columns. 
  //necessary for Libreoffice/Openoffice to accept the column widths.
  //values are in unit twentieths of a point (1/1440 of an inch)
  //if widths of table cells are in percent, then this is only to store the relations
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblGrid tblGrid = table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid();
  if (tblGrid == null) tblGrid = table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid();
  for (org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblGridCol tblGridCol : tblGrid.getGridColList()) {
   tblGrid.removeGridCol(0);  
  }
  //first column
  tblGrid.addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(colWidths[0]));
  //other columns
  for (int c = 1 ; c < colWidths.length; c++) {
   tblGrid.addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(colWidths[c]));
  }     
 }
 
 static void hideFirstCell(XWPFTableRow tableRow) {
  //set gridBefore
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTrPr trPr = tableRow.getCtRow().getTrPr();
  if (trPr==null) trPr = tableRow.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
  for (org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDecimalNumber gridBefore : trPr.getGridBeforeList()) {
   trPr.removeGridBefore(0);  
  }
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDecimalNumber gridBefore = trPr.addNewGridBefore();
  gridBefore.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
  //set wBefore 
  for (org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblWidth wBefore : trPr.getWBeforeList()) {
   trPr.removeWBefore(0);  
  }
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblWidth wBefore = trPr.addNewWBefore();
  XWPFTableCell tableCell = tableRow.getCell(0);
  wBefore.setW(tableCell.getWidth());
  wBefore.setType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTblWidth.PCT);
  tableRow.removeCell(0);
 }


 static XWPFTableRow getOrCreateTableRow(XWPFTable table, int r, String[] colWidths) {
  //create a row having count of cells having special width
  XWPFTableRow tableRow = null;
  if (r==0) {
   tableRow = table.getRow(0); 
  } else {
   tableRow = table.createRow();
  }
  //fill up cell list up to needed count
  while (tableRow.getTableCells().size() < colWidths.length) {
   tableRow.createCell();
  }
  //set the widths
  for (int c = 0 ; c < colWidths.length; c++) {
   tableRow.getCell(c).setWidth(colWidths[c]);   
  }
  return tableRow;
 }
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  Map<String, Object> keyValue = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
  keyValue.put("Key1", "Value1");
  Map<String, String> subKeyValue = new TreeMap<String, String>();
  subKeyValue.put("Key2a", "Value2a");
  subKeyValue.put("Key2b", "Value2b");
  keyValue.put("Key2", subKeyValue);
  keyValue.put("Key3", "Value3");
  
  System.out.println(keyValue);
  
  String multiValues = "Multivalued Key";
  
  double[] dWidthsPCT = new double[]{10d, 30d, 10d, 50d};
  
  java.util.stream.Stream<String> stream = 
   java.util.stream.DoubleStream.of(dWidthsPCT).boxed()
   .map(d -> String.valueOf(d)+"%");
  String[] widthsPCT = stream.toArray(String[]::new);
      
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The table:");

  XWPFTable table = document.createTable();  
  table.setWidth("100%");
  
  //set borders
  table.setTopBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE   , 32, 0, "FFFFFF");
  table.setBottomBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE   , 32, 0, "FFFFFF");
  table.setLeftBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE   , 32, 0, "FFFFFF");
  table.setRightBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE   , 32, 0, "FFFFFF");
  table.setInsideHBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE   , 32, 0, "FFFFFF");
  table.setInsideVBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE   , 32, 0, "FFFFFF");
  
  createGrid(table, new int[]{ // 5000 = 100%
    (int)Math.round(5000d/(100d/dWidthsPCT[0])), 
    (int)Math.round(5000d/(100d/dWidthsPCT[1])), 
    (int)Math.round(5000d/(100d/dWidthsPCT[2])), 
    (int)Math.round(5000d/(100d/dWidthsPCT[3]))
   }
  ); 
  
  XWPFTableRow tableRow;
  XWPFTableCell tableCell;
  String key;
  Object objectValue;
  String stringValue;
  int r = -1;
  for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : keyValue.entrySet()) {
   r++;   
   tableRow = getOrCreateTableRow(table, r, widthsPCT);
   
   key = entry.getKey();
   objectValue = entry.getValue();
   
   tableCell = tableRow.getCell(0);
   tableCell.setText(key);
   mergeCellHorizontally(table, r, 0, 1);
   tableCell.setWidth((int)(dWidthsPCT[0]+dWidthsPCT[1])+"%"); // col width 0 and 1
   tableCell.setColor("00B0F0");
   if (objectValue instanceof String) {
    stringValue = (String)objectValue;
    tableCell = tableRow.getCell(1);
    tableCell.setText(stringValue);
    mergeCellHorizontally(table, r, 1, 2);
    tableCell.setWidth((int)(dWidthsPCT[2]+dWidthsPCT[3])+"%"); // col width 2 and 3
    tableCell.setColor("C0C0C0");
   } else if (objectValue instanceof Map) {
    tableCell = tableRow.getCell(1);
    tableCell.setText(multiValues);
    mergeCellHorizontally(table, r, 1, 2);
    tableCell.setWidth((int)(dWidthsPCT[2]+dWidthsPCT[3])+"%"); // col width 2 and 3
    tableCell.setColor("C0C0C0");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, String> mapValue = (Map<String, String>)objectValue;  
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> subEntry : mapValue.entrySet()) {
     r++;
     tableRow = getOrCreateTableRow(table, r, widthsPCT);
     hideFirstCell(tableRow);
     key = subEntry.getKey();
     stringValue = subEntry.getValue();
     tableCell = tableRow.getCell(0);
     tableCell.setText(key);
     mergeCellHorizontally(table, r, 0, 1);
     tableCell.setWidth((int)(dWidthsPCT[1]+dWidthsPCT[2])+"%"); // col width 1 and 2
     tableCell.setColor("00B0F0");
     tableCell = tableRow.getCell(1);
     tableCell.setText(stringValue);
     tableCell.setWidth(widthsPCT[3]); // col width 3
     tableCell.setColor("C0C0C0");
    }         
   }
  }
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordKeyValueTable.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

It produces:

[image]